# Redefinition of 'i' error

Tags: c, for-loop, compiler-errors

So I have the following C code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nWallSegments; i+=4) {
  fscanf(fin, "%le %le %le %le", &wallSegments[i+0], &wallSegments[i+1], &wallSegments[i+2], &wallSegments[i+3]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < nWallSegments; i+=4) {
  nWallPoints += ceil(dist(wallSegments[i+0], wallSegments[i+1], wallSegments[i+2], wallSegments[i+3]) / dWallPoints) - 2;
  // other stuff here
}
```

When I try to compile, I get the following error. Coming from a Python background, I have no idea what is going on. I have searched online for the answer but with no luck.

```
Prog.c:44:12: error: redefinition of 'i'
  for (int i = 0; i < nWallSegments; i+=4) {
           ^
Prog.c:40:12: note: previous definition is here
  for (int i = 0; i < nWallSegments; i+=4) {c
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on the compiler and/or the version of standard C.

In standard C 1999 and later (C99 and C11), it's admissible to declare a variable in the loop itself and, moreover, the scope is only the loop, as in C++.

By compiling with some modern C dialect, your code would have to go fine.

I use GCC with the option -std=c99 (or c11).
In this case, your code goes well for me.

Comment: Thank you! I found this question because I was experiencing the new semantics and was confused about why it DIDN'T give that error. I'm just overthinking things I guess.

Answer (score 3):

You can't declare `i` inside the for loop in ANSI C89. Declare it once outside the for loop.

Comment: So if I declare `i` in the for declaration, the scope is outside of the for loop?

Comment: If you declare it inside the for loop it won't compile on many compilers including default gcc.

Comment: @VedaadShakib No, your code is legal in C99, but you are using a C89 compiler. In C89, variables must be declared in the beginning of a block.

Comment: @YuHao I'm using gnu's gcc.

Comment: @VedaadShakib GCC uses GNU extended C89 by default. Try add `-std=c99` option.

Answer (score 1):

"redefinition of 'i'".  You are defining the variable `i` twice in the same scope.  You can not do that in C.  Remove the 2nd `int` and it should be fine.

Comment: So if I declare `i` in the for declaration, the scope is outside of the for loop?

Comment: Yes, in C.   In C++, the scope is the loop.

Comment: Not true. In C89, it's illegal to define variables inside `for` header. In C99, it has a scope inside the `for` loop, similar to C++.

Comment: OP is using the `gnu89` mode of gcc (the default mode), which permits definition of `int i` in the for-loop, but it puts that into the enclosing scope, instead of just into the scope of the loop.